# How do you make a segue to yourself?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a game where when you finish a level. You have the option to replay that level. So i programmatically created a replay level button to appear when the level is complete, and i told it to perform the selector replay level when touchupinside. And in my replay level method i was basically just going to perform a segue to the level, so as to basically reset everything in that vc. however normally when i programatically perform segues i make a vc segue to another vc, and give it an identifier and perform it. Yet, how in the world would i be able make a segue from my vc to itself?

Comment: Why segue if you could just reset values manually?  It makes no sense.

Comment: well i guess i kind of like the cool animation with the segue

Comment: @CodaFi but i think i could create animation w out segue

Comment: O sweet, i decided to make a button on IB on my vc and dragged out the modal segue to my own vc and set it to hidden, and then all i did was just set the replay button = to it

Comment: Yes, use `kCATransitionPush` for the standard push animation.

Comment: Yes, but you've pushed a new VC onto the stack, which means if I were to restart your game a thousand times, it'd have 1000 VCs on the stack, which is BAD!

Comment: @CodaFi wait, whenever you do a modal view controller, does it just keep pushing stuff on the stack, even if you have a vc that goes to another vc, and on the other vc you have a back button to the first vc. hitting that back button would leave 2 on stack and not just 0? if thats true what the poop do i do !

Comment: @CodaFi o yea, and i use the cross transitional for the modal, how do i code that?

Comment: Think about it.  View controller A pushes to B (2 on the stack), then presents modally (new Nav stack, but technically 3 VCs are present), then B1->B2 (4), B2->B3 (5), then back to B2 which leaves (technically) 4 view controller references.  View controllers presented modally are usually navigation controllers themselves, which means a new nav stack is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be trying to reset a view controller by "segueing to itself", (which in effect means deallocate and reallocate the VC's memory), what you should be doing is resetting the main game loop and setting all values back to some default when the level is restarted.  From a purely technical standpoint, it is simply not possible either.  A navigation controller (which I will assume you are using considering you can successfully change view controllers), manages a stack of view controllers, which when mutated either deallocates, or retains pointers to its view controllers.  In effect, you would be asking your VC object in the array to auto-refresh itself without some nasty memory management problems.